# Adding frequency values with matching column name

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have the following data frame:

[image]

Some background:

`VAR1` is the Unique code, `VAR2` is Person ID and `FREQ` is Total Count.

For example, Person 1 (`P1`) appears 29 times in code `ABCD`, they also appear 98 times in code `EFGH`. What I am trying to do, is make it so it looks like this:

[image]

Basically, I just want the total, so Person 1 has used a specific code (`VAR1`) 127 times. Person 2 has used a unique code 14 times

I'm unsure how to get this to work, as I'm just starting with R.

Answer (score 3):

In base R (where `df` is your data frame):

```
aggregate(.~var2, df, sum)[,c(1,3)]

#  var2 freq
#1   p1  127
#2   p2   14
#3   p3  135
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr we can do this. Assuming df is the name of the data frame:

```
library("dplyr")    
df %>% group_by(VAR2) %>% summarise(count = sum(VAR3))
```

Comment: This works perfectly too using dplyr! Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt[, list(freq = sum(Freq)), by = Var2]

#   Var2 freq
#1:   P1  127
#2:   P2   14
#3:   P3  135
```

**Data:**

```
dt <- fread("Var1 Var2 Freq
            ABCD P1 29
            ABCD P2 2
            ABCD P3 12
            EFGH P1 98
            EFGH P2 12
            EFGH P3 123")
```